# while using "EXEC xp_cmdshell net use" in sql procedure how to handle exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

```
 BEGIN TRY
     EXEC xp_cmdshell "net use Z: \\10.44.111.124\dpsshare Demo@123 /user:balamuralirc /persistent:yes"
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
     ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
     ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
     ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
     ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
     ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

While using this above try catch it's not working is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Are you trying to capture an error from a failed `net use`? What you are doing is a very bad idea. What are you really trying to do? Are you trying to allow your SQL server to access a file from a share under different credentials? As far as `xp_cmdshell` is concerned, there is no error and it has run successfully

Comment: If you must do this, which I strongly advise you not to, have a read of this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/11/return-values-from-xp_5F00_cmdshell/. It looks like you just need to grab the return value from the proc

Comment: yes, am going to create and write a file to that network Shared folder.

Comment: Why and how are you doing that from SQL Server? You should just grant the SQL Server service account the correct rights rather than using xp_cmdshell, let alone hard coding clear text passwords

Comment: hey for example I haveposted this one actual scenario I will fetch from a table and run.

Comment: Are you saying you will fetch the clear text password from a table? It's a better idea to utilise the service account rather than maintaining lots of logins and passwords and using `xp_cmdshell`

Comment: dear nick my issue is while we make a connection if the connection is successful its ok, but if the connection is not successful I need to catch the error and need to return the error.

Comment: The answer below lets you capture the text output. You are doing something very wrong here.  Are you writing a file or making a connection? If you want to make a file on a remote host, do it using the correct tool - that would probably be SSIS, not `xp_cmdshell`

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is just use the returned text to evaluate the success:
If the thought of temp tables upsets you, just use a table variable instead.

```
create table #output (line nvarchar(255) null)
insert #output (line) EXEC xp_cmdshell "net use Z: \\10.44.111.124\dpsshare Demo@123 /user:balamuralirc /persistent:yes"
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * from #output WHERE line LIKE '%System error%' OR line LIKE '%not found%')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Failure'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Success'
END

drop table #output
```